flyway error: how to fix: "Detected applied migration not resolved locally"
We had flyway scripts from 1__xx to 70_xx
I have just added new ones from 71_xx to 83_xxx
migration 14_xx was a rollup of all preceding scripts (a dump), and at that point 2 years ago, migrations 1__xx to 13_xx were deleted from git.
New databases get 14 to latest.
I am trying to run flyway desktop pointing to an existing DB.  Desktop is complaining because it doesnt have scripts 1-13 locally, so gives this error:
Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation
Detected applied migration not resolved locally: 1.
If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted.

The error is from 1 to 13,
How can we tell flyway to ignore missing local scripts?
There used to be a parameter: ignoreMissingMigrations but this does not exist in desktop version 7.2.0 (and we cant upgrade to 7.3.6 because it fails with a java error).

OK, turns out there is a new way to tell flyway to ignore missing local migrations:
-ignoreMigrationPatterns=*:missing
This seems to have replaced ignoreMissingMigrations.  The * means either versioned or repeatable.   Until now I didn't realize repeatable existed.
